# Java - Read the output of a process

Tags: java, process, output

I have the code

```
Process core = pb.start();
if(!core.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.HOURS))
{
    System.out.println("Process destroyed, path " + root.getAbsolutePath());
    core.destroy();
}
String output = IOUtils.toString(core.getInputStream());
return output;
```

It must run the process that should work not more than 3 hours. If it works more, this process should be destroyed, but all generated logs must be collected anyway.
I through it's a right code, but today I have seen that it stopped on the line `IOUtils.toString(core.getInputStream())` because I think it wan't destroyed after calling destroy() and continued working, and IOUtils.toString was waiting it's finished working.
Please advise how to be this that, thanks

Comment: What version of Java you are using?

Comment: Starting processes is very operating-system dependent, but I'd say that it is not safe to assume that the InputStream will continue to exist after you call `Process.destroy()`. Also, the InputStream is a *piped* stream with, in most OSes, a limited-size buffer, meaning that you need to keep reading from it as long as the process lives, otherwise the process will block because it cannot send more output to the pipe. Which is done the most easily and safely by kicking off a separate Thread to read the data.

Comment: @chokdee, Java 8 on Windows 8.1

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, thanks, I will try to do it by the both ways. So, the thread should keep reading and when it's notified, reading should be stopped and the process+thread destroyed?